# Need to have a border around a bunch of div tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have one border around four div elements which will be displayed as a row.
[Check Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAefE.png)

This is the template I'm using:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <div align = "center">
            <h4>Forecasted Cum.Oil (STB)</h4>
            <h3><b>{{cum_oil_rate}}</b></h3> 
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <div align = "center">
            <h4>Forecasted Cum.Water (STB)</h4>
            <h3><b>{{cum_water_rate}}</b></h3> 
           </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <div align = "center">
            <h4>Last Decline Rate</h4>
            <h3><b>{{decline_rate}}</b></h3> 
           </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <div align = "center">
            <h4>Final Oil Rate (STBD)</h4>
            <h3><b>{{final_oil_rate}}</b></h3> 
           </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now I need to enclose these four div elements inside a box.
Can someone help me on how to do this?

Comment: just use this:

.row{ border: 1px solid #000; } but is better if you set a custom class to row and target the custom class in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom class to your `<div class="row my-class">`

Then in your CSS add :

```
.my-class {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-sm-3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Try this

Comment: The above code gives me boxes over every div element. I need one box enclosing all the div elements.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8cUw.png

Comment: so only give border to .row class it will enclose all divs